# Can’t see the picture I’m taking. Screen is black

Tags: canon-50d

The screen is black when I turn the camera on. Once I’ve taken the picture, the picture will show up and then the screen will go black again.

If you press Menu it’s works but not all of the setting are there. I’ve tried to clear the camera settings but the Clear Settings Option is not there.

The camera is a Canon EOS 50D

Comment: Have you searched the Canon website or read the camera manual? – [How to enable live view on the EOS 50D.](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART105128&cat=2807B)

Comment: How long have you had the camera?  Did it ever do what you want?  What have you changed (settings, lens, flash, other attachments)?

Comment: Why do you expect the screen to show you an image before you take a photo ? Are you expecting the camera to be in live view mode, if so you have to **tell the camera to be in live view mode** or it will not know you want to be in live view mode and it will expect that you are going to be looking through the viewfinder to compose your shot. Xiota provided a link to info on how to accomplish that. *If this is not the problem then you need to provide **much more info** so we can have an idea of how to direct you*.

Answer (score 4):

The Canon EOS 50D is a DSLR (Digital single-lens reflex camera). This means that you will *NOT* see a digital live image in normal operation unless you press the shutter, in which case you see a review of the shot taken. Instead you have an optical viewfinder.

The camera operates by having a mirror redirect the light to the viewfinder instead of the sensor. As it is not hitting the sensor, you cannot get a digital live image on the back screen. This kind of operation would need a mirrorless camera.

However, you can emulate this by going to the live-view mode. This flips the mirror out of the way, so you can use the sensor to record a live image. Please note that this will seriously cripple your autofocus. And you cannot use the optical viewfinder during live view.

Xiota already gave you the link for enabling live-view: [Enable Live View on EOS 50D](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART105128&cat=2807B)